# Issue while debugging within a conda environment in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, miniconda

I'm using VS code (version 1.84.2) on Linux. To debug my python code, I downloaded the latest Python extension (version 2023.20.0). As I need my code to run on a certain conda environment, I selected the correct python interpreter as specified [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Then, I got this prompt: "We noticed you're using a conda environment. If you are experiencing issues with this environment in the integrated terminal, we recommend that you let the Python extension change "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to false in your user setting". Here is a picture of the [Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bDsI.png). So I did (by clicking on "yes").

Now, if I try to simply run the code everything seems to be working fine. Unfortunately, that's not the case if I instead try to debug the file. What I get is the classic type of error as if the conda environment was not correctly activated.

```
ModuleNotFoundError
```

The only workaround I could find to debug my code in the correct conda evn was to:

1. Go in my folder dir
2. Activate my conda env

```
conda activate env
```

3. Run VS code

```
code .
```

Is there something else (maybe more practical) I could do? I was using VS code on another machine last year and I am quite sure I did not have this issue.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: please add the text from your screenshot as text as well. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541